# Does Windows kill a service that doesn't respond to signals?

Tags: windows-10, windows-services

I have a service that works as `Local System` and refuses to stop sometimes.

The service process gets a termination signal, does a cleanup but couple of threads remain running because of the bug.

SCM reports to Event Log with Event ID 7011:

> A timeout (30000 milliseconds) was reached while waiting for a transaction response from the ... service.

After that, services is shown as stopped in the Services window in management console and in the WMI.

But how does Windows deal with service if it doesn't terminate? I cannot restart the service: the process of the old service run is still locking files and bound to ports.

I expect Windows to kill unresponsive process but I cannot find any documentation or settings about that.

30000 msec seems to be taken from `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\ServicesPipeTimeout` (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/839803/the-windows-trace-session-manager-service-does-not-start-and-event-id). But after 30 sec I get only event, process is still there.

According to crash dump, main thread has been terminated, and there are couple of threads waiting on socket in some `WaitForSingleObject`.

We've already reported the bug to vendor and they're trying to fix it. But it's mostly the question what to do to kill this process, whether it's possible to clean it up without reboot.

Comment: Your question belies the underlying problem of why you cant' restart it.  There is a locked condition that the service controller would normally wait for the process+threads to gracefully shut down but isn't.  Therefore, you're experiencing a deadlock condition in which case the service waits for it's predefined duration before giving up.  If you want to restart the service, you need to kill the processes manually.  if you want to fix this long term, you need to contact the software vendor.  If you want a deeper analysis, load up procmon and procexp to diagnose in more detail or dump and debug

Comment: @thepip3r Thank you for suggestion. The bug has been already reported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your service is probably stopped but the threads are still running,
so it is in a zombie state.
Threads are notoriously hard to stop under Windows, and if they are stuck
in an uninterruptible system call then they are absolutely unstoppable.

The only solution is to better design your service, such that the threads
may be signaled to stop, and that signal is set within the service's
OnStop() method.

The threads should always timeout on all system calls, and check their
stop condition when the timeout is triggered.

The alternative might be for the OnStop() method to use `thread.Abort()`
to stop the threads. This is usually a bad idea because it is unknown
what the thread might be doing when stopped and in what state will
the resources it is modifying be after the abort
(which might in addition be ineffective).

Comment: I didn't even know that there are uninterruptable system call in modern Windows. What calls are uninterruptible? I can't do a crash dump now, but, as far as I remember, there are two threads, one of which is in `WaitForSingleObject` call and the other is waiting for data on socket. Are both of them uninterruptable? If not, what's the way to stop them? (I've just found `Win32_Thread` and will experiment with it.)

Comment: Wait for a semaphore may be uninterruptible, waiting for network certainly is. Don't abort your threads - add timeouts to all your waits.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to source code. Hopefully, vendor will fix it soon.

Comment: Only the vendor can solve this problem. If your problem and its solution are now clear you might mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: When I mentioned `Win32_Thread` I meant terminating threads externally, not from offending process. But it seems threads cannot be terminated from outside. At least, `Win32_Thread` has no methods. (I completely agree that threads should finish gracefully and try to design my own apps this way.)